# git diff must compare only from a certain offset or char. column in a line

Tags: git, compare

How git diff compare only from a certain offset column in a line, eg the two log below should be **not different**

```
index 7e2d6d7..cb88ce6
--- a/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
+++ b/mnt/OSraw/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
@@ -1,46 +1,175 @@

-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.32.0, UID=0
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
-[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local

+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.32.0, UID=0
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
+[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
```

Please help out!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`textconv`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files) diffs. While the docs say it's for diffing binaries, what "binary" means here is really just anything that's difficult to work with in its original form.

```
git config diff.myfilter.textconv "sed 's,^\\[[^]]*] , ,'" 
echo lightdm.log diff=myfilter >> .git/info/attributes
```

that `sed` strips leading bracketed words off the lines before the diff sees them, to just white out a fixed number of initial columns you'd do something like `s,..........,----------,`.